# Зависит ли результат запроса от порядка выполнения функций LAST_DAY и TRUNC?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

Не получаю ожидаемый результат при комбинациии функций `LAST_DAY` и `TRUNC`:

```
select LAST_DAY (TRUNC (sysdate, 'DAY')) from dual;

LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSD
-------------------
2021-07-31 00:00:00

select TRUNC (LAST_DAY (sysdate), 'DAY') from dual;

TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSD
-------------------
2021-07-26 00:00:00
```

Почему эти запросы не дают одинаковый результат?

Какая разница между:

1. Получить сегодняшний день без временной составлющей (усечь до полуночи).
2. Затем получить последний день месяца.

И

1. Получить последний день месяца (со временем).
2. Затем избавиться от временной составлющей.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [LAST_DAY and TRUNC - order of execution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68528113) от участника [@michelson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4174701/michelson)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/68528113

Answer (score 3):

Маска [формата даты](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ROUND-and-TRUNC-Date-Functions.html#GUID-8E10AB76-21DA-490F-A389-023B648DDEF8) `DAY` в функции `TRUNC` означает, как это не странно, первый день недели, а не начало дня.

Чтобы усечь дату до полуночи (или избавится от временной составлющей), надо использовать маску `DD` (синонимы `DDD`, `J`). Она используется по умолчанию и указывать её не обязательно:

```
select trunc (last_day (sysdate)) from dual
/
TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSD
-------------------
2021-07-31 00:00:00
```